# Zend framework 2 and Twig (with the ZfcTwig module) - losing layout template content if action template is rendered

Tags: layout, zend-framework2, twig

I'm trying to use ZF2 with the ZfcTwig module. I have basic structure from the Skeleton Application:
view->layout->layout.phtml (or layout.twig)
view->application->index->index.phtml (or index.twig)

if I use the next pair: layout.twig and index.phtml - layout.twig is rendered correctly by the ZfcTwig module, the result for index.phtml (default rendering) is correct also.

But if I try to use content template as a twig template (both twig files) - I'm getting only index.twig with correct render, but nothing from layout template (layout.twig or even layout.phtml)

Did anybody has the same situation?

Comment: Update: ZfcTwig module has the next option:
'disable_zf_model' => false
This turns second layer rendering off.
turning this on will change the situation, but I'm not sure that is the right way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use twig layouts, it works great with ZfcTwig

in index.twig

```
{% extends 'layout/layout.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    Here your template
{% endblock content %}
```

in layout.twig

```
{% block content %}{{ content|raw }}{% endblock content %}
```